# Binding behavior changes depending on the invocation (shiny vs. non shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

Invocation of the following code has a different binding behavior depending if it's running under shiny or not. I can't justify it in any way.

```
# app.R
source("b.R")
print("foo after source")
print(foo)
x()
print("setting foo in app.R")
foo <- c(1,2)
x()
```

```
# b.R
foo <- c("XXX")

x <- function() {
  print("inside function")
  print(foo)
}
```

Result if I invoke it with Rscript:

```
whatever$ Rscript app.R 
[1] "foo after source"
[1] "XXX"
[1] "inside function"
[1] "XXX"
[1] "setting foo in app.R"
[1] "inside function"
[1] 1 2
```

Result if I invoke it under shiny

```
> shiny::runApp('whatever')
Loading required package: shiny
[1] "foo after source"
[1] "XXX"
[1] "inside function"
[1] "XXX"
[1] "setting foo in app.R"
[1] "inside function"
[1] "XXX"
```

It's as if it does early binding for the function closure only when running under shiny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening here is that when you run `shiny::runApp()`, shiny creates it's own environment to run all the shiny code in. (I think related to [this](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/237)). But when you call `source()` directly, no separate environment is created and everything goes straight to the global environment. You can see this if you add `print(environment())` to your `app.R` file. You'll see when you `source("app.R")` this returns `<environment: R_GlobalEnv>` but when you call `shiny::runApp()` you'll see a different environment name.

So when you call `source()` in `app.R`, again it's loading all the content into the local environment by default. This creates `foo<-"XXX"` in the global environment and the environment for `x()` is set to the global environment. This is true for both invocations. But when you kick it off with `shiny::runApp`, that's no operating in the global environment so when you do `foo <- c(1,2)` you are not updating the global environment, but just the local shiny environment. The global `foo` still exists and thanks to lexical scoping, the global value is the one `x` will find.

A quick fix would be to use

```
source("b.R", local=TRUE)
```

in `app.R`. This will load the values from `b.R` into the local environment rather than the global environment. This will work under both circumstances since calling `source()` directly on "app.R" will already run in the global environment so it won't work any differently.

Comment: Ok but I would assume that the sequence of events when I load from shiny is that it creates the shiny environment, and runs the code in that environment, which would run the source, which would run the assignment of the "global", but that global var would be bound to the environment that code is being parsed in... which is the shiny one.

Comment: Nope. The global environment is above the shiny environment. It's a special environment that is parent to everything in the workspace (well, almost everything). Shiny can just create it's own environment, it can't change what R calls the global environment. That's why you need `local=TRUE`, that says do things in the current environment, not the global enviroment.